# Get transaction hash for a call to smart contract in Go

Tags: go-ethereum

I have been following https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/dapp/native-bindings to make a call to a smart contract.

Given an Ethereum transaction can take anywhere between 15 seconds to minutes, I don't want to keep my process stuck for minutes. I would like to create a cron job to check on the state of the transactions. For this I need access to the transaction hash. The document does not show how to get it using `Go` packages.

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a sample script to send an ERC20 Transfer and get tx hash:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "context"
    "crypto/ecdsa"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
   
)
const (
    CHAIN_ID        int64 = 1234
)
var (
    RPC_URL string
    token_addr      common.Address
)
func main() {

    RPC_URL = os.Getenv("RPC_URL")
    eclient, err := ethclient.Dial(RPC_URL)
    if err!=nil {
        fmt.Printf("Can't connect to ETH RPC: %v\n",err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    if len(os.Args) != 5 {
        fmt.Printf("Usage: \n\t\t%v [priv_key] [token_addr] [dest_addr] [amount]\n\n\t\tSends erc20 tokens to another address using transfer() function\n",os.Args[0])
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    var copts = new(bind.CallOpts)

    from_pkey_str := os.Args[1]
    if len(from_pkey_str) != 64 {
        fmt.Printf("Sender's private key is not 66 characters long\n")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    contract_addr := common.HexToAddress(os.Args[2])
    dst_addr := common.HexToAddress(os.Args[3])
    amount_str := os.Args[4]

    tok_amount := big.NewInt(0)
    _,success := tok_amount.SetString(amount_str,10)
    if !success {
        fmt.Printf("Incorrect amount provided on the command line")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    erc20_token,err := NewERC20(contract_addr,eclient)
    if err!=nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to instantiate ERC20 contract: %v\n",err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    symbol,err:=erc20_token.Symbol(copts)
    if err!=nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error during call: %v\n",err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Symbol: %v\n",symbol)

    from_PrivateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(from_pkey_str)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Sprintf("Error making private key: %v\n",err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    from_publicKey := from_PrivateKey.Public()
    from_publicKeyECDSA, ok := from_publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Printf("Couldn't derive public key for Sender")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    from_address := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(*from_publicKeyECDSA)
    from_nonce, err := eclient.PendingNonceAt(context.Background(), from_address)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error getting account's nonce: %v\n",err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    gasPrice, err := eclient.SuggestGasPrice(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error getting suggested gas price: %v\n",err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    big_chain_id := big.NewInt(CHAIN_ID)
    txopts := bind.NewKeyedTransactor(from_PrivateKey)
    txopts.Nonce = big.NewInt(int64(from_nonce))
    txopts.Value = big.NewInt(0)     // in wei
    txopts.GasLimit = uint64(10000000) // in units
    txopts.GasPrice = gasPrice

    signfunc := func(address common.Address, tx *types.Transaction) (*types.Transaction, error) {
        signer := types.NewEIP155Signer(big_chain_id)
        signature, err := crypto.Sign(signer.Hash(tx).Bytes(), from_PrivateKey)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error signing: %v\n",err)
            os.Exit(1)
            return nil,nil
        }
        return tx.WithSignature(signer, signature)
    }
    txopts.Signer = signfunc

    tx,err := erc20_token.Transfer(txopts,dst_addr,tok_amount)
    if err!=nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error sending tx: %v\n",err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Tx hash = %v\n",tx.Hash().String())
}
```

the ERC20 is the standard ERC20 contract, you can generate it with these commands:

```
abigen --abi token.abi --pkg main --type Token --out token.go
```

`abigen` command is in `cmd/abigen` in `go-ethereum` sources and must be compiled with `go build .` command

Comment: It seems there is a difference in return types  between a functions that return a value and a function that does not. A function that does not return a value returns a transaction, where as a function that returns a value does not.

It means it is not a good idea to return a value by a mutable function.